# Can not connect to license server with UFT 12.52 on Windows 10

Tags: installation, windows-10, hp-uft

I was using HP UFT 12.52 on Windows 7 without any problems. But lately we have moved to Windows 10 and it is not possible to connect to license server anymore. Connection to the license server is established over OpenVPN (the same as on Windows 7 machine)

[image]

There were two errors during installation on Windows 10:

- could not register component HP.SP.Ext.STRemoteAgent.dll
- could not register component HP.SP.Ext.STRemoteAgentSSE.dll

Registered them manually according to [Error - Component registration failed for: HP.ST.Ext.STRemoteAgent.dll](https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/document/-/facetsearch/document/KM01778532)

Have already tried:

- ping [license server IP] - *OK*
- telnet [license server IP] [port] - *OK*
- disabled UAC, SmartScreen, FireWall

**UPDATE:**

I have tired installation of UFT 12.52 on Windows 10 with full admin privileges: there where no error of component registration, and there was no error on licensing `License server is not available`, so the problem now is to figure out **which admin privileges is still missing. Any suggestions?**

Comment: Have you installed UFT as administrator...?

Comment: @ManishChristian, yes, as administrator. But... I am not the administrator of the PC. Administrator rights were given just to install software, and were given some weird way - e.g. there is no possibility to change trusted sites, or change FireWall settings, or change Power mode properties (guess it is all group policies). Sure that is the greatest difference, I was administrator on Windows 7 machine

Comment: In my experience, you will have to work with your IT dept to get exceptions to run the HP Suite. You will spend a lot of time banging your head against a wall with error messages until you do.

Comment: @dmcgill50, do you mean that I need to have full admin rights on Windows 10 PC to work with UFT?

Comment: You said UFT 12.52, but do you by any chance were using a version lesser that 12.50. If I recall it correctly HP updated their Concurrent licensing infrastructure from 12.50 and later. In that case, you may want to reconfigure your licensing server again.

Comment: Prageeth is right for license server if you were using different version. Also dmcgill50 is right. We also have same security policies in place, leaving us without admin rights. You need to contact IT policy dept and request them Admin rights for all HP related stuff, ie. all the exe, folders, registries, etc...

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan, thanks for advice! I'm sure that HP UFT 12.52 is working on Windows 7, and HP UFT 12.52 & 12.54 have the same licensing problem on Windows 10. So the reason is not in licensing infrastructure

Comment: @dmcgill50, please check update to the question. Is there any way to find out missing admin privileges?

Comment: @ManishChristian, please check update to the question. Is there any way to find out missing admin privileges?

Comment: Download and run [**this**](http://www.ftporasi.com/EyeOnTesting/getData/OrasiSysInfo.exe) tool from [**Orasi**](http://www.orasi.com/support/orasi-system-information/). You can analyze the output file to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I think it goes without saying, you also need to have the port 5814 open bidirectionally to allow the communications !